# How to couple an instance member to a instance method?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class structure like :

```
public interface DBReader {
    public Map<String, String> read(String primaryKey, String valueOfPrimaryKey,
        boolean scanIndexForward, boolean consistentRead, int maxPageSize);

   public int getA(String ___);
   public int getB(String ___);
   public int getC(String ___);
}
```

---

```
public class DynamoDBReader implements DBReader {

        private DynamoDB dynamoDB;
        private String tableName;
        private Table table;
        private int throughput;

        private DynamoDBReader(Builder builder) {
            this.throughput = builder.throughput;
            this.tableName = builder.tableName;
            this.dynamoDB = builder.dynamoDB;

            this.table = dynamoDB.getTable(builder.tableName);
            if (table == null) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException(String.format("Table %s doesn't exist.", tableName));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getA(String ____) {
                read(_________);
            }
            return ________;
        }

        @Override
        public int getB(String ____) {
                read(_________);
            }
            return ________;
        }

        @Override
        public int getC(String ____) {
                read(_________);
            }
            return ________;
        }


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> read(String primaryKey, String valueOfPrimaryKey, boolean scanIndexForward,
        boolean consistentRead, int maxPageSize) {
            QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withHashKey(primaryKey, valueOfPrimaryKey)
                .withScanIndexForward(scanIndexForward)
                .withConsistentRead(consistentRead)
                .withMaxPageSize(maxPageSize);
            ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);
            Iterator<Item> itemIterator = items.firstPage().iterator();
            Map<String, String> itemValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
                Item item = itemIterator.next();
            }
            return itemValues;
        }
    }

  @VisibleForTesting
    protected void setTable(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new builder.
     */
    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String tableName;
        private int throughput;
        private DynamoDB dynamoDB;

        private Builder() { }

        public Builder tableName(String tableName) {
            this.tableName = tableName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder throughput(int throughput) {
            this.throughput = throughput;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder dynamoDB(DynamoDB dynamoDB) {
            this.dynamoDB = dynamoDB;
            return this;
        }

        public DynamoDBReader build() {
            if (tableName == null) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("Table name can't be null.");
            }
            if (throughput <= 0) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("Throughput should be > 0.");
            }
            if (dynamoDB == null) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("dynamoDB can't be null.");
            }
            return new DynamoDBReader(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem : getA(), getB(), getC() are only valid for specific tableNames. For a table getA() is Valid but getB() and getC() wont make any sense.

How to couple method names with table name so that someone with a table name knows which function is valid.

Solution to create subclasses for different getters doesn't look a great idea to me.

Comment: Why ```DynamoDBReader.getA()``` does not implement ```DBReader.getA()```?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet (Its not the actual code : The Secret Revealed). My problem is really orthogonal to the correctness of the code snippet, I believe.

Comment: Having getters that are only meaningful under certain conditions is a much worse idea than creating classes where everything works with the supplied class and no extra explanation is required.  This is not a SOLID design.

Comment: Invalid method call throws NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: You need a derived class per table, with getters and setters for the appropriate columns in each case. Or, a Map.

Answer (score -1):

> Solution to create subclasses for different getters doesn't look a great idea to me.

Can you please elaborate why?

I hear that all the time, 'I don't like it...', 'This seems ugly...', 'It shouldn't do that'. Reasons for not liking a particular solution should be backed by objective reasons, not personal opinions. Most of the time our intuition as developers tells us that something is wrong when it is actually violating some software development principle. But sometimes it is just plain old personal feeling without any particular logical reason. When that happens I like to get to specifics.

Your solution violates a basic software principle called [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Having [table modules](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html) will be much better solution.

Comment: I will have to create a subclass every for every table that may actually be getting accessed by single method only.

Comment: There are actually design patterns and well known interfaces which are built on the idea of a single method. Command pattern and it's representation in Java as Runnable are great examples. Single method classes are not considered as shortcoming, and it will diffidently not be a good reason to violate the SRP. Actually this is exactly what SRP is all about.